# Why does MXToolBox not return MX records for my domains hosted with Amazon Route 53?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, amazon-route53

Ok, this should be straight forward and I'm ashamed I haven't been able to figure this one out for myself, but...

I've recently discovered Amazon Route 53 DNS services and I'm now using this for the domains which I manage. In order to sanity check my MX records, I use MXToolBox.com to show the MX records and run a quick SMTP check on each MX server.

Here's an example of one of the domains in Route 53:

[image: Route 53]

However when I try to run the query `mx:nylandconstruction.co.uk` on MXToolBox.com, I am [what seems to be] redirected to the query results for `a:nylandconstruction.co.uk` and the MX records are not returned:

[image: Example query]
[image: Example result]

So I check from command line:

```
$ dig nylandconstruction.co.uk MX +short
10 mx01.nylandconstruction.co.uk
15 vps02.aws.joe.nyland.tk.
```

Which confirms that the MX records are present.

If I query MX servers for gmail.com, MXToolBox.com behaves correctly:
[image: mx:gmail.com]

So it appears that it's only my domains that are not returning valid MX records to MXToolBox, at least.

Does anyone have any ideas why? Does the above work correctly for anyone else using Route 53 for their DNS?

Comment: To confirm, the URL I am using to check from MXToolBox.com is: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3anylandconstruction.co.uk&run=toolpage#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug with mxtoolbox. This happens on all .co.uk, .co.nz ... domains. I guess it doesn't like TLDs with two fields. You can check with `mx:google.co.uk`, `mx:thetimes.co.uk`, `mx:nzherald.co.nz`, you always get an A record.

Comment: Great! Why didn't I think of that? :) I've opened up a thread on the MXToolBox.com forums so hopefully they can fix this. http://community.mxtoolbox.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1890316&p=1927652#p1927652

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently change your records? You may need to wait for the TTL to expire on the previous records. They are reporting correctly for me.

```
nylandconstruction.co.uk mail is handled by 10 mx01.nylandconstruction.co.uk.
nylandconstruction.co.uk mail is handled by 15 vps02.aws.joe.nyland.tk.
```

Comment: The domain has been running on Route 52 for approx. 1 week, so MX records have been present on there for some time, hence MXToolBox should return *some* MX records. Furthermore, MXToolBox queries the name servers for the domain directly, so any changes to MX records in Route 53 should show up pretty much straight away from queries performed my MXToolBox.com...

Comment: Also, I'm aware that the `host` command is returning MX records for the domain, as you have pointed out, hence I included the output of dig in my original question. Thanks for confirming this from another location, though.

Comment: This seems to be some bug at mxtoolbox, because it seems to be happening on ALL .co.uk domains. Try for yourself with `mx:google.co.uk`, `mx:thetimes.co.uk` or whatever...

Comment: Same problem with .co.nz domains...